# Есть ли библиотека которая работает с Active Directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

Начал изучать Python нравиться лаконичность и простота языка, но вот с AD или с Ldap подружить его толком не смог, какая-то не читаемая жесть получается. Мне нужно авторизоваться на домене и получить полные данные пользователя. Как мне это реализовать? Неужели нет готового кода? Применительно к Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует модуль [ldap3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ldap3). Есть и для Python2, и для Python3.

Ещё можно посмотреть на модуль [activedirectory](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/activedirectory/) (не уверен, что поддержан Python3).